# My code about a rock paper scissors game is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import random
rock = '''
    _______
---'   ____)
      (_____)
      (_____)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

paper = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
          _______)
         _______)
---.__________)
'''

scissors = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
       __________)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''
rps = [rock, paper, scissors]
player_choice = int(input('''Welcome to the rps tournament, where you will face some of the best rock, paper, scissors players. Please type 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors.\n''')) - 1
print("\nyou play\n" + rps[player_choice])
computer_choice = rps[random.randint(0, 2)]
print("\nyour opponent plays\n" + computer_choice)

if player_choice == computer_choice:
  print("It's a draw!")
elif player_choice == 0 and computer_choice == 2:
  print("\nYou win!")
elif player_choice == 1 and computer_choice == 0:
  print("\nYou win!")
elif player_choice == 2 and computer_choice == 1:
  print("\nYou win!")
else:
  print("\nYou lose!")
```

what's wrong??? it is always giving me a "you lose" message whenever I run the code. Iv'e tried screwing around with how I figure out who has won, but to no success. Iv'e been working on this one for a solid 20 min, thought I'd ask for some help.

Comment: Print out `computer_choice`. Is it what you expect it to be, either `0`, `1`, or `2`?

Comment: `computer_choice == 2` should be `computer_choice == paper` or whatever string you're using, and so on for each option. You can also use `random.choice(rps)` instead of `randint` which isn't the ideal way to pick from a list randomly. The numbers aren't very clear -- I'd normalize input one time and go with the spelled words the rest of the code, or let the user input "rock", "paper" and "scissors" -- it's too much cognitive overhead for both the user and the code to keep track of which number is which item. Neat ASCII hands, BTW.

Comment: Better solution imo would be to make both "choices" be ints, so `computer_choice = random.randint(0, 2)`, and then do `rps[computer_choice]` when you print, same as you do for `player_choice`.

Comment: Try using a debugger next time.  One minute in a debugger would reveal your mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The `player_choice` is an integer.  The `computer_choice` is an ASCII graphic, a string. These two will *never* be equal.  Instead, handle the two variables in the same fashion:

```
computer_choice = random.randint(0, 2)
print("\nyour opponent plays\n" + rps[computer_choice])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your computer choice should be de index `random.randint(0, 2)` and not the element of the list.